# How many base-out configurations would be possible in sleazeball?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem: In a baseball there are 24 different "base out" configurations (runner on first - two outs, bases loaded- none out, and so on). Suppose that a new game, sleazeball, is played where there are 7 bases (excluding home plate) and each team gets 5 outs an inning. How many base-out configurations would be possible in sleazeball?

Attempt: In baseball there are 8 base configurations. There is 3 out configurations in baseball. Then the number of base out configurations is equal to  product of baseball base configurations times the base out configurations, thus 8*3 = 24.

I am stuck. Please can someone please help me? Thank you.

The answer is 5*2^7 = 640.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each base can either be empty or contain a player.  That's two possible states per base.  There are seven independent bases.  So that's $2^7$ states over all bases.  Now, multiply by 5, since there are 5 possibilities for number of "outs" for each base state.